# How to install platex in TexWork

Tags: platex

I need to write a Japanese report, but I am using the Texwork, with MikTex 2.9 .

So I need to install the package platex.

I do not know where to install such a package, I try to search in the MikTex Package Manage, but find nothing about platex.

Can anyone give me a hand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MiKTeX does not ship Japanese pLaTeX. (platex.exe is available, but it's not Japanese but Polish) You have to install TeX Live instead, in order to use Japanese pLaTeX.

Another choice for writing Japanese would be using LuaTeX. If you are allowed to use LuaTeX, you can write Japanese document using luatexja package:

```
%#! lualatex test.tex
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}
\begin{document}
こんにちは、日本
\end{document}
```

Package luatexja and LuaTeX engine are both shipped with MiKTeX, so you can try immediately.